# Create word fields in python-docx to automatize footer from upon page 2 of the word document (e.g. # Page / # Total Pages)?

Tags: python-docx

I'm trying to automatize a word - file generation via python docx. I created a template with the first page and its specific footers and headers; now I only need to implement this footer, starting from upon the second page:

Name                        Page # / Total Pages                  Date

all I want to know is how to configure this footer for all pages starting from the second, without influencing the headers or footers of the first page of the template. My problem is: Can I create word fields via python docx (e.g. the Pages and NumPages fields for the midpart; that's the only problem)..?

If not, can I somehow only insert the "Name" and the "Date" part into the footers from upon page 2 of the template without affecting the mid-part which I would then prepare in the template as well... ?

Attempted code on a template already containing the Pag/NumPag fields in the middle of the footer deleted the middle part (Result was a file where "Hello" was written in the lower left corner in the footer, and the Pag/NumPag of the template (Hello.docx) disappeared:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

doc = Document("Hello.docx")
footer = doc.sections[0].footer
parag = footer.paragraphs[0]
parag.text = "Hello"
parag.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
parag.style = doc.styles["Footer"]

doc.save("Hello2.docx")
```

Comment: Check out `Section.different_first_page_header_footer = True` in the documentation here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section.different_first_page_header_footer. Then `section.footer` should be the one that appears on 2nd and later pages.

Comment: cheers buddy but the main problem is that I don't know how to insert the page number in the footer of each page in a word docx file via python docx...?

Comment: It sounds like you asked two questions. StackOverflow works best when you keep it to one per post. `python-docx` doesn't yet have a way to insert a field, which is what an auto-updated page-number is. If you search around you might find someone who has successfully injected that XML into a run.

Comment: yeah, felt I was not clear enough with my first request.. cheers!